# ¿Por que el video incrustado en un iframe en local aplica el css pero subido a internet no aplica el estilo?

Tags: html5, css3, iframe, estilos

El problema es que un estilo se ve aplicado cuando trabajo con el iframe en local, pero al subirlo a internet el iframe no respeta ningun estilo.

[image: Aqui si aplica el estilo (Local)]
[image: Aqui no aplica el estilo (internet)]

el html es este

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ilUCwLLdltQ"
                            frameborder="0"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                            allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

el CSS es este

```
.iframe-container{
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}

.iframe-container iframe{
    width: 100%;
}
```

He estado buscando varias soluciones pero nada me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comienza por eliminar el `width` y `height` que están en tu `iframe`, ya que es css inline y se lee después de tu archivo css. luego has esto con tu css para que tu video sea adaptable a cualquier pantalla.

```css
.iframe-container {
    width: 95%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0 56.25%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe, .iframe-container object, .iframe-container embed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ilUCwLLdltQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿En el servidor de internet tienes subido el css?

Es el primer error que se me ocurre.

O que lo tengas subido y puesto en otra carpeta o con otro nombre, suelen ser errores comunes, nos pasa a todos.

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es simple, tu pagina no esta "leyendo" tu css.

Recomendaciones:

1. verifica mayusculas y minisculas en tu archivo css: recuerda que en localhost estilo.css es capas de leerse con todas sus variables en mayuscula y minuscula (ESTILO.CSS, EStilo.CSS,ESTILO.css,etc,etc); sin embargo en servidor son archivos diferentes ya que las urls son exactas. (si pones css/estilo.css en tu html igual debe estar en tu directorio.
2. Para verificar si lee tu archivo css da click derecho/ver codigo fuente a la pagina y luego dale click al link donde esta la url de tu css y si carga es porque si esta bien y si no es porque cometiste un error al digitar el nombre de la url.